# WinRM, HTTPS listener setup within Template loses private key after Sysprep

Tags: windows, server, winrm, windows-server-2022, sysprep

I have a windows 2022 gold template used deploying machines.  A winrm https listener is setup initially to allow encrypted communication between setup servers and the new machine being deployed.  The self-signed cert is local and only used during initial connection.

Afterwards, the cert is replaced on the winrm https listener.   After sysprep, the private key is gone with the error below.  The winrm listener remains.  Any ideas?  I tried a workaround of exporting, marking the keys exportable and re-importing, setting up the winrm listener again.  [image: private key not found]

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have a feeling WinRm needs to be configured again on the new instances made from the sysprep'd  image